# ERROR Installing GeoIP-Python on windows

Tags: python, mingw, geoip

I am trying to install GeoIP-Python-1.2.4 on Windows 7. 
Before I can do that, I need to install GeoIP-1.4.6. 
I am using README.MinGW instructions for installation. I used MinGW and got through ./configure. When I do 'make', I get following error:

```
*** Warning: This system can not link to static lib archive libGeoIP.la.
*** I have the capability to make that library automatically link in when
*** you link to this library.  But I can only do this if you have a
*** shared version of the library, which you do not appear to have.
libtool: link: warning: undefined symbols not allowed in i686-pc-mingw32 shared
libraries
ar cru .libs/libGeoIPUpdate.a  GeoIPUpdate.o md5.o
ranlib .libs/libGeoIPUpdate.a
creating libGeoIPUpdate.la
(cd .libs && rm -f libGeoIPUpdate.la && cp -p ../libGeoIPUpdate.la libGeoIPUpdat
e.la)
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Harp/GeoIP-1.4.6/libGeoIP'
Making all in apps
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/Harp/GeoIP-1.4.6/apps'
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"GeoIP\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"GeoIP\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.4
.6\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"GeoIP\ 1.4.6\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"support@maxmind.com
\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -
DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE
_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1
 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"GeoIP\" -DVERSION=\
"1.4.6\" -DLITTLE_ENDIAN_HOST=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_ZLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_GETTIME
OFDAY=1 -DHAVE_VSNPRINTF=1 -DHAVE_VSPRINTF=1 -I. -I../libGeoIP -Wall -DSYSCONFDI
R=\"/usr/local/etc\" -Wall   -O3 -I/usr/local/include -c geoiplookup.c
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/
local/lib -lwsock32 -o geoiplookup.exe geoiplookup.o ../libGeoIP/libGeoIP.la
mkdir .libs
gcc -O3 -I/usr/local/include -o geoiplookup.exe geoiplookup.o  -L/usr/local/lib
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a -lwsock32
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0x8af): undefined reference
 to `getnameinfo'
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0xa1c): undefined reference
 to `getaddrinfo'
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0xa48): undefined reference
 to `freeaddrinfo'
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0x14ae): undefined referenc
e to `getaddrinfo'
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0x14e7): undefined referenc
e to `freeaddrinfo'
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0x162c): undefined referenc
e to `getaddrinfo'
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0x170f): undefined referenc
e to `freeaddrinfo'
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0x2713): undefined referenc
e to `getaddrinfo'
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0x281f): undefined referenc
e to `freeaddrinfo'
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0x2ffb): undefined referenc
e to `getaddrinfo'
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0x30bf): undefined referenc
e to `freeaddrinfo'
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0x32b3): undefined referenc
e to `getaddrinfo'
../libGeoIP/.libs/libGeoIP.a(GeoIP.o):GeoIP.c:(.text+0x3377): undefined referenc
e to `freeaddrinfo'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [geoiplookup.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Harp/GeoIP-1.4.6/apps'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

When i simply try to install GeoIP-Python, I get following error:

```
Harp@T500 ~/GeoIP-Python-1.2.4
$ python setup.py  install
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'GeoIP' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
/MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IInclude -Ic:\Python27\include -Ic:\Python27\PC /Tcpy_Geo
IP.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\py_GeoIP.obj
py_GeoIP.c
py_GeoIP.c(31) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
py_GeoIP.c(33) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
py_GeoIP.c(37) : error C2065: 'GeoIP_GeoIPObject' : undeclared identifier
py_GeoIP.c(37) : error C2275: 'GeoIP' : illegal use of this type as an expressio
n
        c:\mingw\msys\1.0\home\harp\geoip-python-1.2.4\include\GeoIP.h(74) : see
 declaration of 'GeoIP'
py_GeoIP.c(38) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
py_GeoIP.c(40) : error C2065: 'flags' : undeclared identifier
...
...
py_GeoIP.c(275) : error C2065: 'GeoIP_GeoIPObject' : undeclared identifier
py_GeoIP.c(275) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
py_GeoIP.c(275) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilati
on
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.ex
e"' failed with exit status 2
```

My objective is to install GeoIP-Python. Any idea how I can do it? or can someone explain what these errors mean?

I tried looking for pre-built option, but was not able to find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try

```
python setup.py build_ext -cmingw32
```

(or `-cmingw`, can't remember.)

This way it'll try to use the MinGW compiler (it defaults, as you can see from the command line, to MSVC)

Answer (score 2):

better choice: [pygeoip](http://code.google.com/p/pygeoip/wiki/Usage) , it's pure python API for MaxMind GeoIP databases,  don't need C API anymore

Answer (score 0):

I got around the linker errors while building the GeoIP C library by altering the LDFLAGS they give in the instructions.  Instead of linking winsock32, I linked ws2_32.  Make check still fails for me, but only on 2 country code by name tests.  The country code by address tests completed just fine.